# How to convert 4 digit Integer value to Time value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with hour values in 4 digit integer. I need to convert the hour value into Time format, as shown here:

```
val  and what I want is ->     hour 
-------------------------------------
 942                         9:42 
1928                         19:28 
1017                         10:17 
2031                         20:31
```

Comment: `TIMEFROMPARTS(value / 100, value % 100, 0, 0, 0)`. There are other ways of then formatting that `TIME` to a string, but ideally that should be left to the client.

Comment: Is the input properly constrained to not provide incorrect numbers (I.e. values greater than 2359, any value with second last digit in `6-9`)? If not, what should we do on such input?

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert that formatting should be done in the presentation layer. Extending the example, one can use the T-SQL `FORMAT` function: `FORMAT(DATETIMEFROMPARTS(1900, 1, 1, val / 100, val % 100, 0, 0), 'hh:mm tt');`

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you it has work but the null values goes to the error

Comment: `TIMEFROMPARTS` will return `NULL` if its input is `NULL`, so that can't be the problem. If you need `NULL` to ultimately end up as something else, use `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`. If you need some illegal value that *isn't* `NULL` processed, use `NULLIF`/`CASE` (e.g. `NULLIF(value, 'NULL')` to convert a string `'NULL'` to a proper `NULL`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: it seems like you have an answer here, why not post it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Times in SQL Server have a seconds component as well as hours and minutes (or hours as well as minutes and seconds).  You can convert to a time using `timefromparts()`:

```
select timefromparts(val / 100, v % 100, 0, 0, 0)
```

If you want only the HHMM portion, you can convert back to a string:

```
select convert(varchar(5), timefromparts(val / 100, v % 100, 0, 0, 0))
```

Or, you can just use string operations:

```
select stuff(right( concat('00', val), 4), 3, 0, ':')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8d255703d8acddf558f27fd1eda2c82) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: the stirng type was useful because I have time as 2400 in my database and that goes to error.. Thank You!

Comment: @AmirhoseinAraghi . . . You should probably be storing the values as decimal hours rather than `time` or a string.